# Improve a query to populate a Treeview

Tags: mysql, join, treeview, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to build a query to the database structure below.

[image]

Basically, when a registered user in tbuser table enters the system generates a tuple in tbuser_logger table (which takes its id). Then after that, the user can create a project in tbprojeto table. After it's create a tuple in tbdataid table, which holds the id of the created project and the id of the tuple created earlier in tbuser_logger table, or user information that was logged in at that time and which project he was using.

All other system tables as tbcliente, tbinstituições, tbcar, tbhome, etc., has a foreign key to tbdataid table, so each recorded data will have the information on which project and which user.

I'm trying to mount a SQL to bring all the data that a certain user recorded within a project and out of a project. Thus (with just two tables):

```
SELECT
    t1.datProj_Id,
    t2.projNome,
    t3.instNome,
    t4.cltNome
FROM
    tbdataid t1
    LEFT JOIN tbprojeto t2 ON (t1.datId = t2.projDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbinstituicao t3 ON (t1.datId = t3.instDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbcliente t4 ON (t1.datId = t4.cltDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbuser_logger t5 ON (t1.datUsrLog_Id = t5.usrLogId)
    LEFT JOIN tbuser t6 ON (t5.usr_Id = t6.usrId)  
WHERE 
    (t1.datProj_Id = 12 AND t6.usrId = 8)
    OR (t1.datProj_Id IS NULL AND t6.usrId = 8)
```

My query is bringing the data that I want and so after populate a treeview. But the query has many tuples `null`, which is normal. So how can refine or improve this query to ease the construction of the treeview? Follow the results below:

[image]

If I have just one datid values, as an image below '1', I will have a lot of duplicate tuples with a little database size, bring me about 96k. I could compare before to not put on treeview duplicate results, however it's a big query to dataset in deplhi.

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You say you're getting normal results, so what kind of improvement in the query do you have in mind? What difficulty are you having in constructing the tree view now?

Comment: @RobKennedy I wanted to remove the null tuples in query to decrease the dataset size. So, I always will have one not null value in projNome column for example, a lot of instNome and cltNome not null values.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Delphi? It's 100% about SQL.

Comment: @KenWhite yes sorry about that, I put delphi tag thinking in a clear query to populate the treeview. I edit my question showing now another scenario when I have only unique dataid values.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use `IS NULL` in your SQL query, why not also insert some `IS NOT NULL`? At least to remove all the entirely `NULL` result lines.

Comment: I will take I look if I can use some `IS NOT NULL`